# Enable facebook login in iOS

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using UIActivityViewController for sharing image and text to Facebook and Twitter. If I logged in with Facebook in the settings page, the facebook icon will showing the UIActivityViewController. However if I didn't already login then the facebook icon is not showing in UIActivityViewcontroller. How to enable facebook icon without login

How can I prompt the user to log in when they try to share, instead of failing to share?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[viewImage];

    UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    avc.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, nil];
    [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

(iOS 6.0 and up)

I call this function:

```
- (void)askUserToLoginToFacebookInSettings
{
    if(![SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        // Facebook Service Type is Available

        SLComposeViewController *slVC   =   [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler handler =   ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
        {
            [slVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };

        slVC.completionHandler = handler;

        [slVC.view setHidden:YES];

        [(MainViewController *)[(SettingsLayoutView *)delegate delegate] presentModalViewController:slVC animated:NO];

        [slVC.view endEditing:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Service Unavailable!!!");
    }
}
```

Then user is presented with alert, that is visible in your provided screenshot. No Post form will be visible.

but before that - I ask permission to do that:

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0)
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
         ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSDictionary *options = @{
          ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"xxxxxxxxxxx",
          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"user_birthday"],
          ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
    };

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:options
         completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) 
    {
         if (granted) 
         {
             NSLog(@"access granted");
         } 
         else 
         {
             NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);
         }
      }];
}
```

Comment: It's correct. But i'm using UIActivityViewController for all service like twitter,mail,facebook. When click the button it shows all the service. I didn't use only facebook. If i use only facebook your answer is correct.

Comment: You could ask permission (see my edit) - maybe then it will start working.

Comment: I don't want to use SLComposeViewController. Is there any way to use UIActivityViewController. I think you didn't understand my question

Comment: Ok, sorry. Good luck then!

Comment: Do you know for UIActivityViewController?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that one, but I believe in either case You would probably need to ask permission to use these features. As - without asking permission, I was also unsuccessful to present Settings alert. So the same might apply to your situation, unfortunately.

Comment: Is apple reject my app or not without asking permission?

Comment: No - I mean - I think - without asking permission, You probably will not be able to get "Settings" alert to appear. You should test that (ask permission, and then see if alert will appear. if nothing changes - then I am wrong. If alert appears - then You have your answer - no other way, but to ask permission..)